# AWS Datapipeline RDS to S3 Activity Error: Unable to establish connection to jdbc://mysql:

Tags: amazon-web-services, data-pipeline

I am currently setting up a AWS Data Pipeline using the RDStoRedshift Template. During the first RDStoS3Copy activity I am receiving the following error:

"[ERROR] (TaskRunnerService-resource:df-04186821HX5MK8S5WVBU_@Ec2Instance_2021-02-09T18:09:17-0) df-04186821HX5MK8S5WVBU amazonaws.datapipeline.database.ConnectionFactory: Unable to establish connection to jdbc://mysql:/myhostname:3306/mydb No suitable driver found for jdbc://mysql:/myhostname:3306/mydb"

I'm relatively new with AWS services, but it seems that the copy activity spins up an EC2 instance for the copy activity. The error clearly states there isn't a drive available. Do I need to stand up an EC2 instance for AWSDataPipeline to use and install the driver there?

Answer (score 0):

Typically when you are coding a solution that interacts with a MySQL RDS instance, esp a Java solution such a Lambda function written using Java runtime API or a cloud based web app (ie - Spring Boot web app),  you specify the driver file using a POM/Gradle dependency.

For this use case, there seems to be information here about a Driver file: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-jdbcdatabase.html